# Python bs4 BeautifulSoup: findall gives empty bracket

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, findall

when i run this code it gives me an empty bracket. Im new to web scraping so i dont know what im doing wrong.

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=laptop'

r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

container = soup.findAll('li', {'class': 's-result-item celwidget '})
#btw the space is also there in the html code

print(container)
```

results:

```
[]
```

What i tried is to grab the html code from the site, and to soup trough the `li` tags where all the information is stored so I can print out all the information in a for loop.

Also if someone wants to explain how to use BeautifulSoup we can always talk.
Thank you guys.

Comment: I get 16 items with your code.

Comment: The code above is missing a comma. Please copy paste correctly.

Comment: still didnt get anything

Comment: Maybe you're getting a bad response. Can you print `r.text` and `r.status_code`?

Comment: @t.m.adam yes is can

Comment: Add a header with a User-Agent, and your code works.

Comment: @jlaur sorry, i dont get what you are saying. What do i need to change?

Comment: So what is the output?

Comment: @t.m.adam i get the source code and a number

Comment: 200 and the same html you get when you open the url in a browser, right?

Comment: @t.m.adam i got 503 and the html yes

Comment: No, 503 is an error code. Try @jlaur's answer.

Comment: @t.m.adam doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a working code that grabs product and price would could look something like this.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=laptop'
r = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla Firefox'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
container = soup.findAll('li', {'class': 's-result-item celwidget '})
for cont in container:
    h2 = cont.h2.text.strip()

    # Amazon lists prices in two ways. If one fails, use the other
    try:
        currency = cont.find('sup', {'class': 'sx-price-currency'}).text.strip()
        price = currency + cont.find('span', {'class': 'sx-price-whole'}).text.strip()
    except:
        price = cont.find('span', {'class': 'a-size-base a-color-base'})
    print('Product: {}, Price: {}'.format(h2, price))
```

Let me know if that helps you further...

Comment: i've got one more question, imagine you have 4 divs one with class="a" second with class="b" etc how do i selet in which one i want to soup. Do i need to do something like this? soup.find('div', {'class': 'c'}).otherpath other path stands for what comes after it?

Comment: You create a new object from the full soup. smaller_soup = soup.find('div', {'class': 'a'}). Read the docs. They're extensive.

Comment: so i can do soup.find('div', {'class': "a"}).div.div.find('div', {'class': 'f'}).string? or is this code returning a error?

Comment: If the site has that structure that's probably valid. But in that case you'd probably be better off just calling the div with the f-class directly...

Comment: because i want to scrape information about laptops and print it, but i want to do it in a path like for i in container: i.div.find('div' {'class': 'b'}).etc